# Boundedness of the generating sequence of Supremum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Suppose that {$x_n$} is a bounded sequence and for each positive integer $n$, let $$b_n=\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},...\}$$ Prove that $b_n$ is bounded and decreasing.

Progress: I have worked out from these definitions.

(1) The sequence {$x_n$} is bounded if there is a number $M$ so that $\mid x_n\mid \leq M$.

(2) The sequence {$x_n$} is decreasing if $x_1\geq x_2\geq x_3\geq ...$.

I am stuck to this problem. Any help/hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For every $n\in\mathbb N$, it is true that $$|b_n|=|\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1},\dots\}|\leq|\sup\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}|.$$ Because $(x_n)$ is bounded, the supremum on the right hand side is a real number, so the sequence $(b_n)$ is actually bounded.

Also, $(b_n)$ is decreasing because $$b_{n+1}=\sup\{x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots\}\geq\sup\{x_{n},x_{n+1},\dots\}=b_n.$$

Comment: Thank you... It is a great help for me as a beginner. Now, I will make the proof basing from these ideas.